# Android Ice Cream Sandwhich versus Gingerbread HTTP Post

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-post

Fairly new to Android and created/tested my app using Android 2.3.5 (Gingerbread).  I have multiple database connections I used HTTP Post (but did not use AsyncTask) and everything worked great.  I then tested it on Android 4.0.3 (Ice Cream Sandwhich) and I'm not able to connect to the database, therefore my app does not work.

Wondering what do I need to consider to allow this working app to run on Ice Cream Sandwhich?  I did move the database connection out of the UI Thread (but not AsyncTask) and it still does not connect.

Here is my class I created outside of my UI Thread:

public class InputsRecapGetTask {

```
public InputsRecapGetTask(InputsRecap activity,
        ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.progressDialog = progressDialog;

    getDatabase();

}

public void getDatabase() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    progressDialog.show();

    // create new default httpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // create new http post with url to php file as pararmenter
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://test.com/returnBBD.php");

            // assign input text to strings
            user = Login.userStatic;
```

Comment: use asynctask. Asynctask should work and it is recommended by most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you examine the logs? IIRC, Android 4 requires that http requests are not done from the main thread. There must be a message telling this.

On the other hand, please keep in mind that

1. if you turn the screen, the Activity that created the AsyncTask may
   be removed from the screen (forever) and replaced by another
   Activity; it (the 1st Activity) will receive the result, but will not show anything;
2. in Android 4, all AsyncTasks are by default serviced by a single
   thread; this guarantees that responses arrive in the order the
   requests are made, but also means that the 2nd request will start only after the
   1st one finishes (or times out).

According to MVC, the data retrieval must be done by the model, not by the controller (Activity) whose lifetime is that of a View.

Comment: I went ahead and tried the AsyncTask in it's own class, and still have the crash.  The database retrieval is used in the UI, therefore according to the logcat, I believe that is where the issue is coming from.  I tried to move the AsyncTask prior to  SetContentView, but that did not solve the issue either.

Comment: Update: I used the AsyncTask AND moved the task to the screen prior to ensure it's uploaded prior to the new UI.  This fixed the problem of the crash in Ice Cream Sandwich.  Thank you!